# How to filter two properties in the JSON - mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I have following `JSON format` in the mysql table `statistics` and the column is `stats`

```
{
     "stats":{
          "gender":{
             "male":40, //40 is percentage
             "female":50
          },
      "cities":[
         {
            "name":"Melbourne",
            "country":"AU",
            "percentage":20
         },
         {
            "name":"London",
            "country":"GB",
            "percentage":10
         },
         {
            "name":"Sydney",
            "country":"AU",
            "percentage":14
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### What I know (Using -> or JSON_EXTRACT):

```
select * from statistics as a where a.stats->'$.stats.gender.male' < 41

It returns the above row since male percentage is 40.
```

#### Requirement:

I need to fetch records of **country** **AU** and **percentage** **20**.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function.

Test:

```sql
SET @`country` := '"AU"',
    @`percentage` := '20';

SELECT
  `stats`,
  `a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].country',
  `a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].percentage'
FROM
  `statistics` `a`
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(`a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].country', @`country`) AND
  JSON_CONTAINS(`a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].percentage', @`percentage`);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHYFNKSrWRBzds7k1tWtdc/0).

Comment: I don't think this resolution works? As per the db-fiddle, it returned both 3 cities. Am I missing anything?